# Validar pasaporte y DNI españoles

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

Necesito una expresión regular para validar el código de pasaporte español con jQuery.

Esta es mi función.

```
$.validator.addMethod('pasaporte', function(value,element){
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}$/.test(value);
});
```

Necesito los patrones que sigue el código de pasaporte al igual que el tipo de formato DNI de España.

Por ejemplo.

> ```
> AAA123456A
> ```

Comment: @lois6b, él necesita el formato para pasaporte (no para DNI). En realidad no sé el patrón que siguen estos números, también habría que buscarlo en Google a ver cómo funciona.

Comment: @elchiniNet, en la union europea no necesitas pasaporte, vale el DNI. Yo por ejemplo no he sacado nunca el pasaporte. Pero si, hasta que no espeficique .. mal vamos xD

Comment: @lois6b, según leo en la web, el número de pasaporte aquí en España es el mismo que el del DNI, esto no lo puedo comprobar ahora, tendría que mirar mi pasaporte cuando llegue a casa.

Comment: Bueno, al final parece que no es verdad lo de que son iguales. No se le puede hacer mucho caso a [los ForoCocheros](http://www.forocoches.com/foro/showthread.php?t=1873168) :)
@lois6b, [aquí lo puedes consultar](http://verne.elpais.com/verne/2016/08/09/articulo/1470757698_679060.html) para que crees la expresión regular correcta.

Comment: @ElChiniNet gracias. lo he añadido a mi respuesta.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

El [pasaporte español](http://verne.elpais.com/verne/2016/08/09/articulo/1470757698_679060.html) es:

- 3 letras y 6 dígitos y opcionalmente 1 letra (caracter de control para las autoridades)

La regex seria:

```
/^[a-z]{3}[0-9]{6}[a-z]?$/i
```

y tu codigo:

```
$.validator.addMethod('pasaporte', function(value,element){
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]{3}[0-9]{6}[a-z]?$/i.test(value);
});
```

---

---

Los DNI españoles pueden ser:

- NIF (Numero de Identificación Fiscal) - 8 numeros y una letra<sup>1</sup>
- NIE (Numero de Identificación de Extranjeros) - 1 letra<sup>2</sup>, 7 numeros y 1 letra<sup>1</sup>

<sub>1 -  Una de las siguientes: TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE</sub>
 <sub>2 - Una de las siguientes: XYZ</sub>

Por tanto tu [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) ha de ser una comprobacion doble:

```
var nifRegex = /^[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]$/i;
var nieRegex = /^[XYZ][0-9]{7}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]$/i;
```

Pero eso es para comprobar el formato.

A parte, si quieres ser más riguroso, hay una formula para saber si el numero es valido.

Se divide el numero entre `23` y si el resto coincide con la posicion de la letra del documento en la lista `TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE` entonces es valido.

Ej:

`12345678z` es válido. ¿Por qué?

> `12345678 % 23 = 14` y en la posicion `14` del `string TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET` es la letra `Z`

Quedando todo:

```
function validar(value){

  var validChars = 'TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET';
  var nifRexp = /^[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET]$/i;
  var nieRexp = /^[XYZ][0-9]{7}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET]$/i;
  var str = value.toString().toUpperCase();

  if (!nifRexp.test(str) && !nieRexp.test(str)) return false;

  var nie = str
      .replace(/^[X]/, '0')
      .replace(/^[Y]/, '1')
      .replace(/^[Z]/, '2');

  var letter = str.substr(-1);
  var charIndex = parseInt(nie.substr(0, 8)) % 23;

  if (validChars.charAt(charIndex) === letter) return true;

  return false;
}

$.validator.addMethod('dni', function(value,element){
    return this.optional(element) || validar(value);
});
```

**Ejemplo de la comprobacion de DNI y Pasaporte**:

```js
function comprobar(elemID) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);



  if (validar(elem.value.trim(), elemID) || elem.value.trim() == "") {

    elem.style.borderBottomColor = elem.style.borderTopColor;

    return true;
  } else {

    elem.style.borderBottomColor = "red"

    return false;

  }


}

function validar(value, elemID) {

  if (elemID == "DNI") {

    var validChars = 'TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET';
    var nifRexp = /^[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET]$/i;
    var nieRexp = /^[XYZ][0-9]{7}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET]$/i;
    var str = value.toString().toUpperCase();

    if (!nifRexp.test(str) && !nieRexp.test(str)) return false;

    var nie = str
      .replace(/^[X]/, '0')
      .replace(/^[Y]/, '1')
      .replace(/^[Z]/, '2');

    var letter = str.substr(-1);
    var charIndex = parseInt(nie.substr(0, 8)) % 23;

    if (validChars.charAt(charIndex) === letter) return true;

    return false;
  } else {
    return /^[a-z]{3}[0-9]{6}[a-z]?$/i.test(value);
  }
}


$('input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
  comprobar($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Pasaporte: <input type="text" id="Pasaporte"> DNI: <input type="text" id="DNI">

<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Pregunta (desde el desconocimiento total). ¿No convendría validar NIE y NIF juntos, sin importar cuál sea? Me refiero a algo como `/^[0-9XYZ][0-9]{7}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]$/i`

Comment: @Mariano supongo que si HAHAHA empecé con dos regex y no se me ocurrió juntarlos Hahaha gracias

Comment: `[Citation needed]` http://www.interior.gob.es/web/servicios-al-ciudadano/dni/calculo-del-digito-de-control-del-nif-nie