# Comprobar que el valor de un campo cumpla con al menos una de 3 condiciones

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un programa el cual necesitas poner el documento español (NIF,NIE,CIF) y necesito comprobar que los datos introducidos son correctos.

El usuario ingresa el valor en un único input y debe coincidir con el formato de NIF, o de NIE, o de CIF.

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
if (document.formProveedor.NIF.value!="") {
    var regNIF = /^([0-9]){8}([A-Z]){1}$/;
    var regNIE = /^([A-Z]){1}([0-9]){7}([A-Z]){1}$/;
    var regCIF = /^([A-Z]){1}([0-9]){8}}$/;

    if(regNIF.test(document.formProveedor.NIF.value) == false) {        
        alert("El NIF introducido no es correcto.");
        document.formProveedor.NIF.focus();
        return false;   
    }else if(regNIE.test(document.formProveedor.NIF.value) == false){
        alert("El NIE introducido no es correcto.");
        document.formProveedor.NIF.focus();
        return false;
    }else if(regCIF.test(document.formProveedor.NIF.value) == false){
        alert("El CIF introducido no es correcto.");
        document.formProveedor.NIF.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EJEMPLOS:**

```
NIF: 74063793K
NIE: Y9945517D
CIF: G82868043
```

- Cuando relleno el campo con un NIF y se ejecuta la función, me salta el alert

  > "El NIE introducido no es correcto."
- Cuando relleno el campo con un NIE y se ejecuta la función, me salta el alert

  > "El NIF introducido no es correcto."
- Cuando relleno el campo con un CIF y se ejecuta la función, me salta el alert

  > "El NIF introducido no es correcto."

Comment: Hola, el problema es muy simple, te olvidaste cambiar NIF pof NIE y CIF en las lineas de if; en `}elseif(regNIE.test(document.formProveedor.NIF.value) == false){` por ejemplo estas probando el NIF con las reglas para NIE, espero te sea de ayuda, saludos

Comment: En la parte del codigo 
    }elseif(regNIE.test(document.formProveedor.NIF.value) == false){     NIF es el campo de donde saco el valor de los documentos. Solo hay un campo donde meter el datos. Quizas deberia cambiar el nombre del campo @the-breaker

Comment: @hayber edité tu pregunta para focalizarla sobre algo concreto: el error que estás mencionando. Cualquier cosa no dudes en mencionarlo.

Comment: Para ver la parte de regex con el DNI español, te recomiendo: [Validar pasaporte y DNI españoles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/67041/127)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He reformulado la forma en que lo haces, y en mi opinión deberías de utilizar algún tipo de dropdown para elegir que tipo de validación quieres, así no tienes que escribir muchas lineas comparando que solo sea NIF, CIF, NIE, etc.

Primero que nada he hecho un array de objetos con su tipo y validación.

```
var validacion = [
    {
        tipo: 'NIF',
        regex: /^([0-9]){8}([A-Z]){1}$/,
    },
    {
        tipo: 'NIE',
        regex: /^([A-Z]){1}([0-9]){7}([A-Z]){1}$/,
    },
    {
        tipo: 'CIF',
        regex: /^([A-Z]){1}([0-9]){8}}$/,
    },
];
```

Con eso he hecho una funcion `validar` que toma dos parametros: `tipo` y `numero`, donde el tipo es NIE, NIF, DNI, CIF... y el numero el valor que quieres comprobar.

```
function validar(tipo, numero) {
  if(tipo == null || numero == null){
    alert('Error en los datos');
    return false;
  }

    var val = validacion.find(x => x.tipo == tipo);

    if (!val.regex.test(numero)) {
        alert('El ' + tipo + ' introducido no es correcto.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Para llamarlo seria así:

```
validar('NIF', '74063693K'); // true
validar('NIF', '740dd693K'); // false
validar('NIE', 'Y9945517D'); // true
validar('NIE', '74063793K'); // false
```

Recuerda que para rellenar el parámetro `tipo`, **estaría bien que utilizaras un dropdown**.

Comment: Repetir un grupo en regex es muy poco eficiente. En vez de `/^([0-9]){8}([A-Z]){1}$/`, conviene siempre `/^\d{8}[A-Z]$/`, y lo mismo para el resto.

Answer (score 4):

Tu problema es que miras uno por uno: si metes un NIF, obviamente no es un CIF y te da el error, de manera similar pasa con un CIF o un NIE.

La solución más sencilla sería algo como (en pseudo-código):

```
function validarID(...)
    if (<es un NIF correcto>)
       return OK
    }
    if (<es un CIF correcto>)
       return OK
    }
    if (<es un NIE correcto>)
       return OK
    }

    return NO_OK
}
```

Pero una mejor solución sería seleccionar el validador primero, en un select, y aplicarlo al dato metido, porque un usuario podría meter por error un valor válido para un NIE cuando realmente quiere meter un CIF.