# Pattern DNI, como puedo engancharlo para que funcione

Tags: javascript, html

Como puedo enganchar esta funcion pattern al formulario que tengo

```
<form action="darAltaCliente.php" method="post">
        <input name="DNI" type="text"placeholder="DNI">*</br></br><!-- Recoger los datos -->
  <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
  <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
    </form>
```

Con esta funcion para comprobar si el DNI es correcto?

```
function nif(dni) {
  var numero
  var letr
  var letra
  var expresion_regular_dni

  expresion_regular_dni = /^\d{8}[a-zA-Z]$/;

  if(expresion_regular_dni.test (dni) == true){
     numero = dni.substr(0,dni.length-1);
     letr = dni.substr(dni.length-1,1);
     numero = numero % 23;
     letra='TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET';
     letra=letra.substring(numero,numero+1);
    if (letra!=letr.toUpperCase()) {
       alert('Dni erroneo, la letra del NIF no se corresponde');
     }else{
       alert('Dni correcto');
     }
  }else{
     alert('Dni erroneo, formato no válido');
   }
}
```

No se como podría engancharlo, o otra forma mas simple para comprobar el DNI

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Validar pasaporte y DNI españoles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67041/validar-pasaporte-y-dni-espa%c3%b1oles)

Comment: El problema es que no se  como engancharlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción que tienes es suscribirte al evento "change" del input mediante `.addEventListener(evento, callback)`;

De esta forma podrías tener algo así:

```js
function nif(dni) {
  var numero
  var letr
  var letra
  var expresion_regular_dni

  expresion_regular_dni = /^\d{8}[a-zA-Z]$/;

  if(expresion_regular_dni.test (dni) == true){
     numero = dni.substr(0,dni.length-1);
     letr = dni.substr(dni.length-1,1);
     numero = numero % 23;
     letra='TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET';
     letra=letra.substring(numero,numero+1);
    if (letra!=letr.toUpperCase()) {
       alert('Dni erroneo, la letra del NIF no se corresponde');
     }else{
       alert('Dni correcto');
     }
  }else{
     alert('Dni erroneo, formato no válido');
   }
}

document.querySelector('input[name="DNI"]').addEventListener('change', event => {
  const element = event.target;
  const valueToValidate = element.value;
  
  nif(valueToValidate);
})
```

```html
<form action="darAltaCliente.php" method="post">
        <input name="DNI" type="text"placeholder="DNI">*</br></br><!-- Recoger los datos -->
  <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
  <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
    </form>
```