# Que error es el que me da en php?

Tags: php, php7

este es mi código:

```
    <!-- Parte visual -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Validar DNI Carlos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <left>
            <h1>Validar un DNI Carlos</h1>
            <br/>
            <form for="post" action="dni2.php">     
                <label for="guardado">Intoduzca su DNI: </label>
                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['guardado']; ?>" name="guardado" size="10"/>
                <!-- nombre de nuestra variable -->
                <select name="letra" id="letra"> <!-- aqui pondremos las letras para seleccion, el cero cuenta -->
                    <option>T</option>
                    <option>R</option>
                    <option>W</option>
                    <option>A</option>
                    <option>G</option>
                    <option>M</option>
                    <option>Y</option>
                    <option>F</option>
                    <option>P</option>
                    <option>D</option>
                    <option>X</option>
                    <option>B</option>
                    <option>N</option>
                    <option>J</option>
                    <option>Z</option>
                    <option>S</option>
                    <option>Q</option>
                    <option>V</option>
                    <option>H</option>
                    <option>L</option>
                    <option>C</option>
                    <option>K</option>
                    <option>E</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" size=18/>
            </form>
        </left>
    </body>
    </html>
    
    <?php #Ayudado por Javier Gonzalez Raya
        $digitos = $_POST['guardado'];
        $letra = $_POST['letra'];
        $letras = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
        $letrita = substr($letras,$digitos % 23,1); /*formula para calcular el DNI #el strlen=length de mysql Preguntamos si la letra del dni coincide con la formula, DNI valido*/
    
        if ($letra == $letrita){
            echo "Su DNI es correcto";
        }else{
            echo "Su DNI es incorrecto";
        }
    
    ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento calcular validar un dni pero me da siempre incorrecta

Meta lo que meta, se queda igual, no valido, he estado una hora con 3 colegas, mirado el fichero log, copiado su ejercicio y y nada, no logramos localizarlo

Sun Feb 13 20:03:23.546467 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 730] [client 127.0.0.1:57178] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: num in /var/www/html/dni2.php on line 14

[Sun Feb 13 20:03:23.546488 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 730] [client 127.0.0.1:57178] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: num in /var/www/html/dni2.php on line 48

[Sun Feb 13 20:03:23.546493 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 730] [client 127.0.0.1:57178] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: LetraDni in /var/www/html/dni2.php on line 49

[Sun Feb 13 20:06:24.816042 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 732] [client 127.0.0.1:57184] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: guardado in /var/www/html/dni.php on line 14, referer: http://localhost/dni.php?guardado=12345678&Letra=Z&submit=Enviar

[Sun Feb 13 20:06:24.816064 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 732] [client 127.0.0.1:57184] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: guardado in /var/www/html/dni.php on line 48, referer: http://localhost/dni.php?guardado=12345678&Letra=Z&submit=Enviar

[Sun Feb 13 20:06:24.816069 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 732] [client 127.0.0.1:57184] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Letra in /var/www/html/dni.php on line 49, referer: http://localhost/dni.php?guardado=12345678&Letra=Z&submit=Enviar

[Sun Feb 13 20:06:32.163422 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 728] [client 127.0.0.1:57186] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: guardado in /var/www/html/dni.php on line 14, referer: http://localhost/dni.php?guardado=&Letra=T&submit=Enviar

[Sun Feb 13 20:06:32.163452 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 728] [client 127.0.0.1:57186] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: guardado in /var/www/html/dni.php on line 48, referer: http://localhost/dni.php?guardado=&Letra=T&submit=Enviar

[Sun Feb 13 20:06:32.163457 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 728] [client 127.0.0.1:57186] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Letra in /var/www/html/dni.php on line 49, referer: http://localhost/dni.php?guardado=&Letra=T&submit=Enviar

[Sun Feb 13 20:07:11.474094 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 729] [client 127.0.0.1:57188] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: guardado in /var/www/html/dni.php on line 14, referer: http://localhost/dni.php?guardado=12345678&Letra=Z&submit=Enviar

[Sun Feb 13 20:07:11.474113 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 729] [client 127.0.0.1:57188] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: guardado in /var/www/html/dni.php on line 48, referer: http://localhost/dni.php?guardado=12345678&Letra=Z&submit=Enviar

[Sun Feb 13 20:07:11.474118 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 729] [client 127.0.0.1:57188] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: letra in /var/www/html/dni.php on line 49, referer: http://localhost/dni.php?guardado=12345678&Letra=Z&submit=Enviar

Por favor no encuentro el fallo y no hay ningún fallo de sintaxis aparentemente y el post no get por lo que no se porque se me muestra la información la url eso no debe de pasar y muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Estás revisando el archivo dni2.php con una petición GET, siendo que el formulario se envía a dni.php. El primero nunca tendrá poblada la superglobal $_POST

Comment: es mi amigo carlos y le ayude a meterse aqui le puse yo la captura el tiene puesto en el action dni.php, porque asi se llama su fichero a los demas compañeros que le he explicado le ha funcionado pero a el no.

Comment: Como dice @ffflabs estas enviando segun tu codigo la información a un archivo que nisiquiera existe, o en caso de que exista deberias revisar que no dependa de ningun otro archivo o cosas asi, estas enviandolo segun eso a `dni2.php` y no a `dni.php`.

Comment: @ffflabs gracias, es lo primero de lo que nos dimos cuenta, pero no ha funcionado, estoy por probar si haciendo el php en un lado y el html en otro, funciona, pero no estoy seguro

Comment: Vale. Pega el código de `dni.php` para ver si te puedo ayudar un poco. Además, cuéntanos adonde tienes algún `num` que ahora no hay ninguno

Comment: Cambia ```<form method="post" action="dni2.php">``` por ```<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">``` ya que el código PHP lo recibes en la misma página más abajo.

Comment: esta es la clase que impartí ayer @ffflabs : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4n5NmtJQbw

Comment: a partir del minuto 32:48

Comment: @DBE ya funciona, era eso, me comi el method, muuuuuuchas gracias <3

Comment: Encontrado @ffflabs, me comi el method a la hora de declarar el post y puse for nada mas

Comment: Me alegro amigo, un saludo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Los errores que te está dando de *Undefined index* es porque no están definidas, por ejemplo `$_POST['guardado']` por llamar alguno. En el código más abajo explico las líneas.
2. Luego estas obtenido los datos por `$_POST` en la misma página que tu formulario, en cambio en tu **action** tienes `action="dni2.php"` cámbialo por `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"` o simplemente quita el *action*, si realmente deseas un archivo aparte deberías crear (dni2.php). 
   En mi ejemplo uso la misma página.
3. Otro error en cuenta si vas a trabajar con más formularios: `<form for="post"` es `method='POST'`
4. Podrías usar una [expresión regular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67041/validar-pasaporte-y-dni-espa%C3%B1oles/67043) para validar tu **DNI**, te dejo enlace de una respuesta en *SOes* para más información.

**Posible ejemplo:**

```
<?php 
    // Acostumbrarte a reiniciar los variables con los que vas a trabajar,
    // te evitara dolores de cabeza XD 
    $msg = $guardar = $digitos = $letra = $style = ''; // (te evita el warning: Undefined index: ...)
       
    // El formulario existe
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) :
            
        // Obtienes datos
        $digitos = $_POST['digitos'] ?? '';
        $letra = $_POST['letra'] ?? '';

        // Los campos (inputs) estan vacios
        if (empty($digitos) || empty($letra)) :
            $msg = '<li>Todos los campos son requeridos</li>';
            $style = 'error';
        else :
            // Creamos un dni a verificar
            $dni = $digitos . ucfirst($letra);
            // Usas un expresion regular para comprobar si es valido
            $formato = preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]$/i', $dni); // NIF (Numero de Identificación Fiscal) - 8 numeros y una letra

            // DNI es valido
            if ($formato) :
                $guardar = $dni;
                $style = 'success';    
            // DNI no es valido  
            else :
                $msg = '<li>El DNI no es valido</li>';
                $style = 'error';
            endif;                
        endif;        
    endif;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Validar DNI Carlos</title>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style: square;
            color: black;
            display: block; position: relative;
            width: 100%; max-width: 300px;
        }
        ul li { padding: 10px;}

        .error { background-color: #ffcccc; }
        .success { background-color: #00e6ac; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <left>
        <h1>Validar un DNI Carlos</h1>
        <br/>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
            <label for="digitos">Intoduzca su DNI: </label>
            <input type="number" id="digitos" name="digitos" max="99999999" <?php if (!empty($digitos)) echo "value='$digitos'";?> />
            <!-- nombre de nuestra variable -->
            <select name="letra" id="letra"> <!-- aqui pondremos las letras para seleccion, el cero cuenta -->
                <option value="0" selected>Selecciona letra</option>
                <option value="T" <?php if (!empty($letra) && $letra == 'T') echo 'selected'; ?>>T</option>
                <option value="R" <?php if (!empty($letra) && $letra == 'R') echo 'selected'; ?>>R</option>
                <option value="W" <?php if (!empty($letra) && $letra == 'W') echo 'selected'; ?>>W</option>
                <option value="A" <?php if (!empty($letra) && $letra == 'A') echo 'selected'; ?>>A</option>
                <option value="G" <?php if (!empty($letra) && $letra == 'G') echo 'selected'; ?>>G</option>
                <!-- etc... -->                    
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" size=18/>
        </form>

        <ul <?php if (!empty($style)) echo "class='$style'"; ?>>
        <?php // Respuesta formulario
            if (!empty($msg)) echo $msg;
            if (!empty($guardar)) echo "<li>DNI: $guardar</li>";
        ?>
        </ul>
    </left>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo tu error porque a los demas le han salido pero toma. Un codigo simple y sencillo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Validador DNI Carlos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Validador DNI Carlos</h1>
        <br/>
        <form method="post" action="dni.php">
            <label for="entero">Introduce tu DNI : </label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['entero']; ?>" name="entero" size="12"/>
            <select name="ltDni" id="ltDni">
                <option>T</option>
                <option>R</option>
                <option>W</option>
                <option>A</option>
                <option>G</option>
                <option>M</option>
                <option>Y</option>
                <option>F</option>
                <option>P</option>
                <option>D</option>
                <option>X</option>
                <option>B</option>
                <option>N</option>
                <option>J</option>
                <option>Z</option>
                <option>S</option>
                <option>Q</option>
                <option>V</option>
                <option>H</option>
                <option>L</option>
                <option>C</option>
                <option>K</option>
                <option>E</option>
            </select>
        <br/>
        <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Validar" size="10" />
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    $dni = $_POST['entero'];
    $letraDni = $_POST['ltDni'];
    $total = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
    $unaLetra = substr($total,$dni % 23,1);
    print "<center>";
    echo "<br/>";
    if ($letraDni == $unaLetra){
        echo "Tu dni es valido";
    }else{
        echo "Tu dni no es valido";
    }
    print "</center>";
?>
```

Espero que te funciones saludo.